# Period of a linear recurrence mod p

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, finite-fields

$\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb{F}} $
$\newcommand{\bs}{\mathbf{s}}$
Given linear recurrence
$$
x_n = a_{1}x_{n-1} + a_{2}x_{n-2} + \cdots + a_kx_{n-k}\pmod p,
$$
for $x_0, x_1, \ldots$ we define its *state vector* $\bs_{m}=(x_{m+k-1}, \ldots, x_m)\in \FF_p^k$. The sequence is determined by choosing $\bs_0$. We define its *characteristic polynomial* to be $\phi(x) = x^k - a_1x^{k-1} - \cdots - a_k$. We say a recurrence is *maximal* if it has period $p^k-1$ for any nonzero choice of initial state $\bs_0$. Clearly this is maximal because no nontrivial sequence can pass through the zero state.

I am trying to prove the following (The Art of Computer Programming Vol 2, sec 3.2.2)

> The recurrence is maximal iff $\phi$, considered as an element of
> $\FF_{p^k}[x]$, has a primitive element of $\FF_{p^k}$ as a root.

I am unsure how to attempt either direction.

Comment: If $\phi(x)$ has a primitive element of $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ as its root, then $\phi(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$ and all its roots are distinct and roots of unity of order $p^k-1$. This implies that the sequence has maximal period. If $\phi(x)$ factors but has distinct roots, then the period is the lcm of the order of the roots. This is automatically less then the maximum (the degrees of the factors add up). The same if $\phi(x)$ is irreducible but its roots are not primitive. If $\phi$ has multiple roots then you get factors $p$ to the period, but it is still less than maximal.

Comment: We may have this question in a different guise here on the site somewhere. Like: What's the maximal order of a matrix in $GL_k(\Bbb{F}_p)$?